# Is it possible to counter and minimise g forces for more speed by design or technology

Tags: g-forces

Apparently humans can survive betwee 3 G and 5 G G-forces.  Is it possible by design or technology to invent and incorporate that technology or design in passenger planes should we surpass all impedements to speed as a species and left with G forces as the only problem.  Fast trans and cars lately tilt the railway or road, or the body of a car or train tils at curves allowing greater turning speed and no overturing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "incorporate that technology or design". Which technology or design are you talking about? Are you asking if it's possible to reduce the g-forces that passengers feel, so that, for example, maybe an aircraft could accelerate at 6 g while the passengers only feel 4 g?

Comment: How would people in a passenger jet be subjected to 3G in the first place?

Comment: The important thing to consider about humans surviving more (or less) than 1g is: for how much time?

Comment: In straight and level flight, 1g is all you’ll ever get regardless of speed. If you can afford wide turns and only moderate accelerations, g protection isn’t required at all (for any speed).

Answer (score 2):

The tilting you described is a way to lessen the effects of G forces on the body.  There are other ways to lessen the effects such as G-suits like military pilots wear, and tilting the seats back to redirect the force.  (as is done in the F-16)

However, it is not possible to reduce or eliminate actual G forces.  This is basic Newtonian physics, and is pretty much absolute.